# Mat-Select only opening when clicked on bottom line

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I implemented Mat-Select from Angular material (TS) and noticed interesting behavior. Dropdown not opening until clicked on bottom line of mat-select and I know when I worked before with Mat-select field it was opening when I clicked anywhere on field. What is the problem?

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{
        topping
      }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

[image: Behaviour]

Comment: Did you override the default style of material ?

Comment: Maybe? I only added link to bootstrap, that might be an issue?

Comment: And do you find a difference in style of the element between your project and the stackblitz ? Could you provide an example with the error ?

Comment: There is no error, that is the point, select simply isnt working how it should... On stacklizt everything works fine, in code it doesnt, I guess that bootstrap messed functionality up

Answer (score 0):

> From documentation
>   https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

---

might be a cache issues or the dynamic data must be loading late (adding a condition might help)

> Stackblits-
>   https://stackblitz.com/angular/rdlobdgvqok?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-overview-example.ts

```
<h4>Basic native select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
  <select matNativeControl required>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

this will surely solve your issues

Comment: I added your code and test it, still, there is no Angular material look now and not opening, only when clicked on bottom of square window, I dont know what is happening

Comment: @Matej update node.js to latest and can you specify which version of angular global/local you are using ,browser   etc. (add angualr.json  to main question  )